# Having trouble understanding nilpotent and supersolvable group in terms of short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, exact-sequence, nilpotent-groups

> $G$ is supersolvable if $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is cyclic for every $i\geq 0$
> where $G_i$ is a normal sequence of $G=G_n$.

According to the lecture note I read, it says that
in the following short exact sequence,

$1\to G_{i+1}/G_i\to G/G_i\to G/G_{i+1}\to 1$

supersolvable group implies that we have successive cyclic extensions of $\{1\}$ for all $i$. From my understanding, this means that for every mapping we have above, kernel of it is cyclic. So following this new definition, we have to have that $1$, $G_{i+1}/G_i$, $G/G_i$ should be cyclic (since short exact sequence means that the image of mapping in the former is equal to the kernel of the latter). The original definition of supersolvable demands that $G_{i+1}/G_i$  is cyclic, but not necessarily $G/G_i$. Where did I have a mistake?

Also, I have another question.

> If $G$ is supersolvable, any central
> extension of $G$ is also super solvable. Hence nilpotent group is
> supersolvable group.

How do I see this? Is there any good reference to it? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every *finitely generated* nilpotent group is supersolvable.  It is not true that any nilpotent group is supersolvable.

In fact, all supersolvable groups are finitely generated.  So take the free nilpotent group on an infinite set as a counterexample.  Or any uncountable nilpotent group, which are known to exist, if we assume the generalized continuum hypothesis (CH), for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was supposed to be supersolvable and cyclic extensions. I've edited it.

Comment: Wouldn't this have been better off as a comment?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm studying representation theory, and the matter of concern is finite groups! I should have made it clearer, but I didn't expect that it doesn't hold for infinite groups

Comment: If you could please point out any flaw in the first question or possible reference for the second one, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sure.  I am not sure, for the first one, what "original definition" you are referring to.  But successive cyclic extensions suggests that all the quotients are cyclic.  Apparently that finitely generated nilpotent groups are supersolvable is well-known.  I'll let you know if I find a proof.

Comment: Thanks so much. According to this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group, the definition doesn't imply that $H/H_i$ is cyclic, but only $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (and that's always a possibility), in the link it says _all_ the quotients are cyclic.

Comment: $G/G_i$ doesn't have to be cyclic, if that's your point.  We just have $G_i$ normal in $G$.

Comment: According to the alternative definition I have in my note, $1\to G_{i+1}/G_i\to G/G_i\to G/G_{i+1}\to 1$ should be successive cyclic extensions, if $G$ is supersolvable. This implies that kernel is cyclic, meaning that the image is cyclic (since it's short exact sequence). But it seems that the definition on the wikipedia doesn't coincide with the one I have in my note.

Comment: Sorry, but, trying to figure out what's happening, if $G$ is in the middle of your short exact sequence, this appears to be a different definition.  It must be equivalent though.  I believe there are several such.